# Rails, render edit form on click

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I have a list of all my "books" on the books.index view. I want to be able to edit them in the same view. Is there a way to render an edit form when I click on one of the Books ?

As of right now, I'm printing out a partial for each book, and I've added an individual form for each book. But then I'd have to hide all of them and append them each time someone clicks on a book.

I'm thinking there should be some kind of way for me to render the same form each time someone clicks on it, and give it a book id, then it will hopefully fill itself with the right information.

Hope this is making sense.
Thanks!

Controller books:

```
class BooksController < ApplicationController
def index
    @Books = Book.all
    @book = Book.new

end

def show
    @book = Book.find(params[:id])
    @chapter = chapter.new
end

def new
    @book = Book.new
    if !current_user.admin?
        redirect_to @book
    end
end

def edit
    @book = Book.find(params[:id])

    if !current_user.admin?
        redirect_to @book
    end


end

def create
    @books = Book.all
    @book = Book.new(book_params)

    if @book.save
        respond_to do |format|
            format.js
            format.html { render action: "index", notice: 'Book was successfully created.' }
            format.json { render json: @book, status: :created, location: @book }
        end
    else
        respond_to do |format|
            format.js 
            format.json { render json: @book.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
            format.html { render action: "index", notice: 'feil' }
        end
    end



end

def update
    @book = Book.find(params[:id])

    if @book.update(book_params)
        redirect_to @book
    else
        render 'edit'
    end
end

def destroy
    @book = Book.find(params[:id])
    @book.destroy

    redirect_to books_path
end

private
    def book_params
    params.require(:book).permit(:title, :pages)
end
end
```

View, books.index

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <section id="page_wrap">
        <h1>books</h1>

        <table id="all_exps">
            <tr>
                <th>Title</th>
                <th>abbr</th>
                <th>pages</th>
                <th>chapter</th>
                <th class="edits"></th>
                <%unless !session[:user_id]%>
                    <% if current_user.admin?  %>
                        <th class="edits"></th>
                        <th class="edits"></th>
                    <% end%>
                <%end%>
            </tr>


            <% @books.each do |book| %>
                <%= render 'book', book: book %>
            <% end %>
        </table>

        <%unless !session[:user_id]%>
            <% if current_user.admin? %>
                <div class="makenew"> 
                    <a href="" class="add_new"> Add Book</a>
                </div>

                <div id="somedialog" class="dialog">
                    <div class="dialog__overlay"></div>
                    <div class="dialog__content">
                        <div class="close"><%= image_tag('icons/delete2.png') %></div>
                        <h2>Add Book</h2>
                        <%= render 'form' %>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <% end%>
        <% end%>
    </section>
</div>
```

View partial _book

```
<tr>

    <td><%= book.title %></td>
    <td><%= book.abbr %></td>
    <td>

    </td>
    <td><%= book.chapters.length %></td>

    <td class="edits show"><%= link_to image_tag('icons/eye.png'), book_path(book) %></td>
    <%unless !session[:user_id]%>
        <% if current_user.admin?  %>

            <td class="edits"><%= link_to image_tag('icons/edit3.png'), edit_book_path(book) %></td>
            <td class="edits"><%= link_to image_tag('icons/delete2.png'), book_path(book),
            method: :delete,
            data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
        <% end%>

    <%end%>
</tr>

    <%= form_for book do |f| %>

        <%= f.label :title %>
        <%= f.text_field :title %>

        <%= f.label :pages %>
        <%= f.text_field :pages %>


        <%= f.submit %>

     <% end %>
```

Book model

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :chapters, dependent: :destroy

    validates :title, presence: true,
        length: { minimum: 3 }
end
```

Comment: Please show your code to help make it clearer.  Controller, models, and view would be useful.

Comment: You have to post some codes so that we can see what you've done so far.

Comment: Start reading about Ajax

Comment: @MichaelGaskill added the codes now, thanks!

Answer (score -1):

You can do this like that:

In your book **index** page after the end of the loop, add an empty `div`.

```
<% @books.each do |book| %>
  <%= link_to "Edit", edit_book_path(book) %>
<% end %>
<div id="book-edit-partial"></div>
```

Next, 
create a new method on the `books_controller.rb` and define in the `route.rb`. Lets say the name of the method is `inline_edit`.

**routes.rb**

```
resources :books do 
  member do
   get :inline_edit
  end
end
```

Now it will generate the route like `books/:id/inline_edit`.

**books_controller.rb**

```
def inline_edit
  @book = Book.find(params[:id])
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js { render :file => "/path/to/inline_edit.js.erb" } # create a file named inline_edit.js.erb
  end
end
```

Now in your newly created `js.erb` file:

```
$('#inline_edit.js.erb').html('render the form of edit with local variable @book') #I guess you can do that
```

then change the `index` page edit book link with:

```
<%= link_to "Edit", inline_edit-method-url, remote: true %>
```

Please learn `ajax rendering` for rails. I put some plotholes in my code. If you study then you'll find that. :) 
Happy coding.